# How do I mock a XML file in RSpec

Tags: ruby, xml, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I have an XML file `hw.xml` that contains hardware info for a node.

```
<node hostname="my_hostname">
  <volume raid="RAID-10">
   ....
   ....
  </volume>
</node>
```

how to mock the xml file such that it should fail the test cases if raid attribute is not equal to RAID-10?

Comment: Show some more details in your test case. How is the file read, parsed, verified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a XML mock using Nokogiri, like this:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml.products {
      xml.widget {
        xml.id_ "10"
        xml.name "Awesome widget"
      }
    }
  }
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

You can see the documentation for this [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder).